# How do I refer a particular folder in Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zip

I download an old code(zip) files from git. Now I want to refer the folder location as load path so that I can use the code to split the zip, but I can see Split error is coming. The code I tried was

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift('c:/rubyzip/lib/zip')
require 'zip/zip'
part_zip_count = Zip::ZipFile.split("C:\junk\AWS Tools.zip", 10240, false)
puts "Zip file splitted in #{part_zip_count} parts"
```

Is it correct to use $LOAD_PATH.unshift? Any help? How to refer the location of the folder as a loadpath?

Comment: i am getting error as it is referring new require 'zip/zip'...i want to refer the require 'zip/zip' from c:/rubyzip/lib/zip

Comment: The `$LOAD_PATH.unshift` is correct. However, the path separators you use  in `"C:\junk\AWS Tools.zip"` are not correct. \ is an escape character.

Comment: Actually, it is not going till there....Error is coming stating Split object is not present...it is referring the default zip/zip where split is not present....

Comment: Are you sure there is a `split` method for `Zipfile`? I looked through the documentation and source code and cannot find a reference to it.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: @charlescaldwell is on the right trail and needs to put his comments as an answer. There is no `split` method. The filename is defined wrong: use single-quotes around the string or reverse the slashes. Ruby is smart enough to know it's Windows and fix the slash direction if you use forward-slashes. Also, if the ZipFile gem was installed correctly there is no point modifying `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: Hi Charles, you are right. they is no method called Split in zip::zipfile. But in older version, it is having Split function . the link is github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip/blob/master/samples/example.rb So, i want to use this...i downloaded this from github & now i want to refer this......Can you help?

Comment: The error message is
c:/split.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `split' for Zip::ZipFile:Class (NoMe
thodError)

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not appear to be with the `require` part of your script.

There are a couple different ways to add a folder to your `$LOAD_PATH` and `.unshift` is one of them. `$LOAD_PATH` is an Array so `$LOAD_PATH << 'C:/Folder/'` will also work.

You mentioned that you got an error message about `split`. This tells you that the script made it past the `require` portion. So, your problems are in other areas of the script.

Upon examining the [documentation](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html) for `Zip::Zipfile`, you will notice that there is no method `.split` for that class. I would suggest reading the documentation for possible methods that fulfill your script's needs. Perhaps [`.extract`](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html#M000153) is what you are looking for.

Once you determine the proper method and refactor, you will run into another problem which is the path to the zip file you wish to interact with. Windows uses \ (backslash) as a path separator. However, Ruby uses it as an escape character.

```
puts "First line\nNext line"
#=>First Line
#=>Next Line
```

This means Ruby is going to try to figure out what `\j` in 'C:\junk' means. You can fix this in two ways.

1. Use forward slashes. `"C:/junk/AWS tools.zip"`.
2. Use `File.join` to construct a path. `File.join("C:", "junk", "AWS tools.zip")`. Doing this means you won't have to worry about what Ruby considers a path separator and what it doesn't. It'll worry about it for you.

Comment: Hi Charles, 
you are right. they is no method called Split in zip::zipfile. But in older version, it is having Split function . the link is https://github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip/blob/master/samples/example.rb
So, i want to use this...i downloaded this from github & now i want to refer this......Can you help?

Comment: There is no `.split` method in the older versions. There will be a `.split` method in the next version of RubyZip, however. It was added to the GitHub repository 2 months ago and there was some changes made to it merely 3 days ago. They even say at the top of the readme file, "This branch for next version of rubyzip. Do not use it on production. Rubyzip interface will be changed!!!" If you really want to use this bleeding edge version, you can download the code, load it into the `$LOAD_PATH` and use it. Or, install the gem from the GitHub repo.